# Scale_color_manual() function not working in R

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm new to R so I hope this question is interesting. Here is the dataset I'm working with:

```
> dput(lgcanet)
structure(list(hour = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 8L, 8L, 
8L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 
13L, 13L, 13L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 17L, 
17L, 17L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 21L, 21L, 
21L, 22L, 22L, 22L, 23L, 23L, 23L), predicted = c("Feeding", 
"Moving", "Standing", "Feeding", "Moving", "Standing", "Feeding", 
"Moving", "Standing", "Feeding", "Moving", "Standing", "Feeding", 
"Moving", "Standing", "Feeding", "Moving", "Standing", "Feeding", 
"Moving", "Standing", "Feeding", "Moving", "Standing", "Feeding", 
"Moving", "Standing", "Feeding", "Moving", "Standing", "Feeding", 
"Moving", "Standing", "Feeding", "Moving", "Standing", "Feeding", 
"Moving", "Standing", "Feeding", "Moving", "Standing", "Feeding", 
"Moving", "Standing", "Feeding", "Moving", "Standing", "Feeding", 
"Moving", "Standing", "Feeding", "Moving", "Standing", "Feeding", 
"Moving", "Standing", "Feeding", "Moving", "Standing", "Feeding", 
"Moving", "Standing", "Feeding", "Moving", "Standing", "Feeding", 
"Moving", "Standing", "Feeding", "Moving", "Standing"), Y = c(0.154681, 
0.674219792, 0.26018171, 0.123956169, 0.770734667, 0.196624589, 
0.100965488, 0.817486337, 0.150570688, 0.210191433, 0.279995373, 
0.522647236, 0.234739907, 0.139925966, 0.686217363, 0.24114481, 
0.184914944, 0.627808135, 0.234325872, 0.254871562, 0.546399513, 
0.248319131, 0.261282084, 0.508018619, 0.227005233, 0.251133647, 
0.549151992, 0.217179979, 0.226309486, 0.590163933, 0.225626231, 
0.228739084, 0.583517505, 0.219801659, 0.252196842, 0.554826957, 
0.213678598, 0.216436233, 0.592714024, 0.181927787, 0.176007486, 
0.673224042, 0.153096459, 0.103211711, 0.791985426, 0.097062644, 
0.076794171, 0.907589555, 0.173318656, 0.291811127, 0.55956284, 
0.114016498, 0.771948996, 0.18684528, 0.10592056, 0.758283747, 
0.196845864, 0.153399026, 0.637745394, 0.288967977, 0.154103192, 
0.545776799, 0.414282403, 0.17916971, 0.477163312, 0.428690807, 
0.188625532, 0.410643344, 0.460762284, 0.185673466, 0.556603437, 
0.360123553), YMIN = c(0.111622584, 0.57558919, 0.178703401, 
0.088143131, 0.687337528, 0.1217464, 0.0733921, 0.755478814, 
0.093856058, 0.1693268, 0.216235582, 0.452992291, 0.189585149, 
0.075280623, 0.621341306, 0.199077922, 0.128682591, 0.559547066, 
0.191776222, 0.188045367, 0.470199491, 0.205963272, 0.201685928, 
0.445531582, 0.186592457, 0.191004511, 0.485288287, 0.18087768, 
0.172783057, 0.524384284, 0.187255536, 0.166292047, 0.511705373, 
0.180626825, 0.196842022, 0.488278071, 0.180383614, 0.170865092, 
0.531781636, 0.147661097, 0.124588753, 0.61272206, 0.119970955, 
0.069121836, 0.738342094, 0.070756358, 0.040137355, 0.861936686, 
0.142587275, 0.228164929, 0.488514426, 0.082217165, 0.689415552, 
0.114563802, 0.077481332, 0.682770968, 0.13755071, 0.113970229, 
0.536293985, 0.20134563, 0.112932108, 0.431542955, 0.318313417, 
0.139101201, 0.377559378, 0.339132576, 0.142921212, 0.308316469, 
0.368743688, 0.132494556, 0.452613721, 0.277533897), YMAX = c(0.197739415, 
0.772850394, 0.341660019, 0.159769208, 0.854131807, 0.271502778, 
0.128538875, 0.87949386, 0.207285318, 0.251056066, 0.343755165, 
0.592302181, 0.279894666, 0.204571309, 0.751093421, 0.283211698, 
0.241147296, 0.696069203, 0.276875523, 0.321697757, 0.622599535, 
0.29067499, 0.320878239, 0.570505655, 0.267418009, 0.311262784, 
0.613015698, 0.253482278, 0.279835915, 0.655943582, 0.263996927, 
0.291186121, 0.655329638, 0.258976493, 0.307551662, 0.621375843, 
0.246973583, 0.262007374, 0.653646412, 0.216194476, 0.22742622, 
0.733726024, 0.186221963, 0.137301586, 0.845628758, 0.12336893, 
0.113450987, 0.953242423, 0.204050036, 0.355457325, 0.630611254, 
0.145815831, 0.854482441, 0.259126758, 0.134359788, 0.833796525, 
0.256141017, 0.192827823, 0.739196803, 0.376590324, 0.195274276, 
0.660010642, 0.510251389, 0.219238218, 0.576767247, 0.518249038, 
0.234329851, 0.51297022, 0.552780881, 0.238852376, 0.660593152, 
0.442713209)), row.names = c(NA, -72L), class = c("data.table", 
"data.frame"), .internal.selfref = <pointer: 0x00000000026d1ef0>)
```

For which I wrote the following script to creat a plot:

```
p1<-ggplot(lgcanet, aes(x = hour, y = Y, fill = predicted, ymin = YMIN, ymax = YMAX)) +
  geom_col(position = position_dodge2()) +
  geom_errorbar(position = position_dodge2()) +
  scale_color_manual(values = c("Stationary" = "white", "Feeding" = "grey", "Moving" = "black" ))



p1<- p1 + labs(x = "Hour of the day", y = "Proportion",fill="Behavioural category" )

p1<-p1+theme(axis.text=element_text(size=17),
           axis.title=element_text(size=20))  + theme_set(theme_classic(base_size = 14)) +
  labs(title = "LGCA") + ylim(0, 1) +  theme(legend.position = "none")
p1
```

However, the call `scale_color_manual(values = c("Stationary" = "white", "Feeding" = "grey", "Moving" = "black" )` was ignored by R, and the plot is displayed with default red, blue and green colors.

What am I doint wrong? I've used this function before and has worked perfectly.

I appreciate your time!

Comment: Use scale_fill_manual.

Comment: @Roland, Thank you for your answer. That kind of worked, but now one of the categories doesn't appear on the plot ("Stationary"). What could be happening? PS: This isn't due to the fact that the colour is white, because even when chaning to black the bars don't appear on the plot.

Comment: That category doesn't seem to be in your data ...